# Jailbreak and iOS 'hardware encrypted' data

Tags: jailbreak, encryption

My understanding of reading apple security document below
http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/pdf/iPad_Security_Overview.pdf

is that using iphone4s or ipad3,

and setting a complex passcode,

the data on the iPhone/ipad is encrypted when iphone/ipad is locked.

If iPhone/ipad is jailbroken, does it mean the original data is lost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two partitions on all iOS devices. One is for the system, other is for the data. Jailbreaking only affects the System partition. So jailbreaking doesn’t affect your data.

Comment: is data on 'data partition' encrypted and cannot be accessed by the jailbroken system ?

Comment: If the jailbroken system asks for your passcode while unlocking, then you can access your data. By the way, can you give a little context on the problem? I can’t see how you could’ve arrived in a situation like this.

Comment: i'm just wondering whether jailbreaking (without supplying passcode while jailbreaking) can bypass ipad3/iphone4s passcode-locked system and access all data (which is supposedly encrypted by the passcode). can it?

Comment: Nope. As I said, it doesn’t modify the data partition, which is encrypted.